# Angular 2 ngModelChange select option, grab a specific property

Tags: angular

I have a dropdown select form in angular 2.

Currently: When I select an option the `option name` gets passed into my `onChange` function as `$event`

Wanted: When I select an option I would like to pass `workout.id` into my `onChange` function.

How can I achieve that?

```
<select class="form-control" [ngModel]="selectedWorkout" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)">
    <option *ngFor="#workout of workouts">{{workout.name}}</option>
</select>
```

`Controller`

```
onChange(value){
  alert(JSON.stringify(value));
}
```

Answer (score 75, accepted):

```
<select class="form-control" [ngModel]="selectedWorkout" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)">
    <option *ngFor="#workout of workouts" [value]="workout.id">{{workout.name}}</option>
</select>
```

OR

```
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedWorkout" (change)="onChange($event.target.value)">
    <option *ngFor="#workout of workouts" [value]="workout.id" >{{workout.name}}</option>
</select>
```

[check this](http://plnkr.co/edit/kcgRsLgURAl4Lf8UzKvD?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you, this was just what I was looking for!

Comment: Why method doesn't triggered in this case?                                                                                                                `<input [ngModel]="selectedProduct" placeholder="Search Conf by Application ID" (change)="onProductChanged($event)"
               list="products" />
        <datalist id="app_ids">
            <select [ngModel]="selectedProduct" (change)="onProductChanged($event)" name="selectedProduct">
                <option [ngValue]="product" *ngFor="let product of products">{{product.name}}</option>
            </select>
        </datalist>`

Answer (score 3):

you could also use [ngValue] inside option:

```
<select class="form-control" [ngModel]="selectedWorkout" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)">
  <option *ngFor="#workout of workouts" [ngValue]="workout">{{workout.name}}</option>
</select>
```