# Angular2,Ionic2: How to navigate to next page only when user selects atleast 2 of the 4 fields?

Tags: angular, button, ionic2, submit-button, navigateurl

I'm currently developing an app in which the home page consists of set of options which the user has to select.The options are 3 dropdown lists with different data in each of them and one text field.At the bottom of the page I've a button when clicked navigates to the next page.But I want the navigation to be done only when the user enters/selects something from 2 of the 4 available fields.

I read about [disabled] function for the button.But in my case I want the button to be enabled only but still the navigation shouldn't work.

I referred this [How do I enable a submit button if 1 or more checkboxes are checked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38224122/how-do-i-enable-a-submit-button-if-1-or-more-checkboxes-are-checked)
But for me the fields are made individually without using a ngFor. And I want the submit button to be enabled always.

Right now this is my html page without any restrictions:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
     <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
  <ion-content>
    <br>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-input type="text" value="" placeholder="Enter Keyword" [(ngModel)]="textype"> </ion-input>
    </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
  <ion-label>Country</ion-label>
    <ion-select (ionChange)="onSelect(selectid)" [(ngModel)]="selectid">
      <ion-option *ngFor="let selectid of countryData" [value]="selectid">
        {{selectid.name}}
      </ion-option>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-item>

   <!--<ion-item *ngIf="compData">-->
     <ion-item>
  <ion-label>State</ion-label>
  <ion-select [(ngModel)]="catid">
      <ion-option *ngFor="let catid of stateData" [value]=catid>
        {{catid.name}}
      </ion-option>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-item>

<ion-item>
  <ion-label>
    Type of Vehicle
  </ion-label>
    <ion-select [(ngModel)]="typeid">
      <ion-option *ngFor="let typeid of vehicles">
        {{typeid}}
      </ion-option>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-item>
<br>
  <button type="submit" (Click)= "searchform" ion-button full > Search </button>

 </ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would actually do a spin-off of the link you provided. Since it seems you have some kind of a form, we can make use of it and look at the object that is created for the form, and see that a minimum of 2 fields need to be filled. In this case, be something else than an empty string.

Since you have a form, you don't actually need the two-way-binding, but if you want, you can of course keep it. But what you need is the `form` tag and `name` attributes for your fields, and for your submit button you need to pass the form value. So your shortened template could look like this:

```ts
<form #myForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submit(myForm.value)">
  <ion-item>
    <ion-input type="text" value="" placeholder="Enter Keyword" name="texttype" ngModel> </ion-input>
  </ion-item>
 <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Country</ion-label>
    <ion-select name="selectid" ngModel>
      <ion-option *ngFor="let selectid of countryData" [value]="selectid.name">
    {{selectid.name}}
      </ion-option>
    </ion-select>
 <ion-item>
 <button type="submit" ion-button full > Search </button>
```

And then your submit-function, loop through the object and use a counter. If the counter then equals 2 or more, navigate to page of your choosing, else do what you want.

```ts
counter = 0;

submit(value) {
   for(let key in value) {
     if(value[key] != '') {
       this.counter++;
     }
   }
   if(this.counter >= 2) {
     // valid, navigate to other page
   }
   else {
     // not valid, do something else
   }
}
```

### [Here's a demo!](http://plnkr.co/edit/491QBIUotn15LD8IkwgR?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks a lot.It's working.But could you please tell me what does this for(let key in value)loop in .ts file do ? Does it run through all the values that we've mentioned in the HTML file ?

Comment: It loops the object and checks if the object created from the form has a value, e.g that catid has a value, if so, we add to counter `counter++`. Then we check the following field etc.... If you look at the plunker, you can see that upon submit I console the form values, so you can see that object that is created, which we loop through the values and see that at least two fields have values :)

Comment: And since it solved your issue, please consider accepting the answer by clicking the grey tick under the voting of this answer, so that it can be helpful to others :) Here's how, if it's unclear :) https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Comment: So if the form is empty the form object looks like this: `{ texttype: "", selectid: "", catid: "", typeid: "" }`