# Dropdown value in angular2 component

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu, angular-ngmodel

I am trying to explore Angular2 with this simple task.
I have a select element,

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selected" (ngModelChange)="selectedChanged()" id="boolopt">
    <option value="yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="no">No</option>
</select>
```

I want to print this selected value onto my console, which I am trying to access in a Component.

```
 @Component({
  selector: 'step',
  moduleId: module.id,
  templateUrl: 'Opt.component.html',
})

export class Opt{
  selected:string = '';
  selectedChanged() {
    console.log(this.selected);
  }
}
```

After going through similar links on how to get the selected value from dropdown list, I could gather so much info. But now I am getting an error

```
Cannot read property 'selectedChanged' of undefined
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You simply miss a quote in first line? Like :
<select [(ngModel)]="selected" (ngModelChange)="selectedChanged()" id="boolopt">
And you should look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35971589/angular-2-ngmodelchange-select-option-grab-a-specific-property

Comment: I have tried it, and getting an error `self.context.selectedChanged is not a function`

Comment: Your code is working perfectly.